# how to set default screen orientation landscape in android app

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to have portrait screen orientation in mobile view and both orientations in tablet view
I didn't define orientation in manifest but I check if the device is not tablet make orientation portrait in code by this line:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

this code works in tablets perfectly but the problem occur when I try to run the app in landscape on tablets, first app runs in landscape and then change to portrait by code. so `onCreate` function run twice. I don't want to do this twice!

for example may I define a variable in `values-sw600dp` for example and use it to change orientation in manifest? or change manifest orientation priority?! (and set orientation in code?!)

Comment: so you want to check if it's a mobile or tablet?

Comment: yes if is mobile only portrait orientation and  if is tblet both orientation!

Answer (score 0):

A work around that I had used, is to supply a main layout for tablets, and i add an invisible view "dummy_for_tablet" and from main activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
         ....
         if( findViewById(R.id.dummy_for_tablet) != null)
         { //it's a tablet }
         else
         { //it's a mobile }
          ...
    }
```